# OpenCart Category.tpl edit a specific product

Tags: php, opencart, categories

How can I add specific text to a product displayed on the Category.tpl

using this setup

```
<?php if ($this->request->get['path'] == 65) { ?> per month <?php } ?>
```

I just don't know what attribute to use. 
I need to add prices manually to each product because in open cart I put their values to zero but have a required add on with the actual price of the item based on how long they would like the service.

Thanks so much
Mark

Comment: Its really unclear what are you asking. Clearly state your requirement as programmer rather than explaining your business procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `/catalog/controller/product/category.php`

Find this line

```
'price'       => $price,
```

change it to

```
'price'       => $price . ($category_id == 65 ? ' per month' : ''),
```

Comment: Thanks but what about if I wanted to add a specific price to each product listed in the category.tpl. I tried $product_id but it has no effect ( instead of $category_id )

Comment: You would need to use `$product['product_id']` in that instance in the for loop instead

Comment: How so?  
Like this `$price . ($product['product_id'] == 54 ? ' per month' : '')` because that gives me a Undefined variable error

Comment: Ah, it's actually called `$result` not `$product`, so you would use `$result['product_id']`